# Trying to use createNativeQuery in Spring Data JPA to get count from database but getting NULL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get count from a postgreSQL database using Spring Data JPA createNativeQuery. However, the query is returning null instead of the actual values even though the query naturally should return some values as it did when it was run in a database console.

here is the controller code for the API

```
@PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @PostMapping("/date-sum")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> sumRecordsWithDate(@RequestBody SearcherDto searcherDto) {

 Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT null AS id, 
count(case when (IS_QUERIED = false AND SUBMITTED = true) 
then 1 else null end) AS pending,  
count(case when ( (SUBMITTED = true)) then 1 else null end) AS submitted, 
count(*) AS totalApplications FROM ANNUAL_RETURNS a LEFT JOIN 
COMPANY c ON c.id= a.COMPANY_FK WHERE (a.FINANCIAL_YEAR_END >=:startDate 
AND a.FINANCIAL_YEAR_END <=:endDate) AND                    
(c.COMPANY_TYPE_FK=:type OR :type=0) AND (a.PROCESS_TYPE_FK =:process OR 
 (:process1=9542 AND :process2=9594 AND :process3=9598)) ", AnnualReturn.class);

//type set the parameters to avoid postreSQL type-error

        q.setParameter("process", new TypedParameterValue(LongType.INSTANCE, processType));
        q.setParameter("process1", new TypedParameterValue(LongType.INSTANCE, processType1));
        q.setParameter("process2", new TypedParameterValue(LongType.INSTANCE, processType2));
        q.setParameter("process3", new TypedParameterValue(LongType.INSTANCE, processType3));
        q.setParameter("type", new TypedParameterValue(LongType.INSTANCE, companyType));
        
// these are never null, so we don't need to type-set them.
        q.setParameter("startDate", start);
        q.setParameter("endDate", end);
        List <AnnualReturn> countList=q.getResultList();


        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonResponse("See Data Object for Details", countList));
    }
```

This is the Annual Return Entity class looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ANNUAL_RETURNS")
public class AnnualReturn implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "IS_QUERIED")
    private Boolean queried;

    @Column(name = "FINANCIAL_YEAR_END")
    private String financialYearEnd;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_FK")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROCESS_TYPE_FK",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Process_Type processType;

}
```

This is the result I expect to get:

```
"status": "OK",
    "success": true,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "data": {
        "totalApplications": 2000,
        "submitted": 560,
        "queried": 60,
    },
    "message": "See Data Object for Details"
```

This is what I am getting instead:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "success": true,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "data": [
        null
    ],
    "message": "See Data Object for Details"
```

This is the request I am sending from postman:

```
{
"startDate": "2014-06-11",
"endDate": "2020-10-14",
"processTypeFk":9542,
"companyTypeId": 6995

    }
```

Please help me with any ideas or suggestions to make the count query return actual values for submitted, queried and totalApplications.

Answer (score 0):

First if all , result cannot be mapped directly to AnnualReturn.class , as lot of sql operation being performed to fetch the result.
List  countList=q.getResultList();
instead it will be :

```
List <Object> countList=q.getResultList();
Iterator iterator = countList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Object row = (Object) iterator.next();
       //set to your new Result Object
       ResultObject obj = new ResultObject();
        obj.setTotalApplications(row[0]); 
        obj.setSubmitted(row[1]);
        obj.setQueried(row [2]);
        // create object and add to list 
        list.add(obj);
    }
    
    Class ResultObject {
        int totalApplications ;
        int submitted;
        int queried ;
    //getter setter
    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am trying to implement it but it doesn't compile. It says..

Array type expected; found: 'java.lang.Object'
on these lines:

obj.setTotalApplications(row[0]); 
        obj.setSubmitted(row[1]);
        obj.setQueried(row [2]);